# Lightbox javascript / flash for pages

Tags: javascript, css, flash

Does anyone know a lightbox in which I can load pages? I found one called lightbox-gone-wild but I am having problems with it.

Answer (score 2):

http://fancybox.net/ ... I've used it with good results in the past.

Comment: My +1 pushed you over 1000 woo.